# How many users do shared hosters stuff on a server?

Tags: vps, shared-hosting

I heard that typically it's around 800 - 1000. Is it true?

What about VPS? How many users usually share a VPS?

Comment: I've heard 42 is the sweet spot.

Comment: @ErikA I've always had good fortune with DEADBEEF

Comment: @WesleyDavid Yes, that is another solid choice.

Comment: i thought this is a legitimate question...

Answer (score 3):

On shared hosting there is no typical, consider a server a pie.

On a shared host, they cut the pie into as many pieces as possible as limited by hardware and acceptable latency (to the average user). The pie is the same pie for everyone. 
(Everyone shares memory, disk, etc to an extent)

On a VPS, you're given the whole pie to yourself, you have control over it. 
The size of your pie is determined by how it's provisioned. (You're guaranteed X MB of RAM, X GB of storage, that is not shared with anyone else).

Comment: Close, but a VPS you dont have the whole pie. If other VMs are sucking up a ton of CPU, your machine will not get its full CPU. Also the hypervisor is allowed to swap out your machine's ram, so if the hypervisor doesnt have much memory, and other VMs are using it, some of your machine may get swapped out. Disk IO is also shared.

Comment: Depends on the VPS provider - I figured my answer would be sufficient given the initial question's nature